# Update table column on different page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to update a column in my table from 0 to 1 when a user clicks on the `X` button to delete a comment. When I try to delete the comment I get the else statement saying not set.

comment_frame.php:

```
if ($userLoggedIn == $posted_by) {

    echo $delete_button = "
    <form action='includes/form_handlers/delete_comment.php?comment_id=$comment_idd'
    method='GET' >
    <button name='delete_com' class='delete_comment btn-danger'
    >X " . $comment_id . "</button></form>";
}
```

delete_comment.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['comment_id'])) {

    $comment_id = $_GET['comment_id'];
    
} else {

    echo "Not set.";
}
```

Comment: I believe so, when I remove the `<form>` part of the code nothing happens when I click the button but when I leave it I get the problem I am currently having.

Comment: You say that the div disappears when you click that button, which suggests that you're having some JS event that gets triggered when you click that button. Can you show that as well? And are you submitting the form using Ajax?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no there's no JS involved.

Comment: @Dharman I added an else statement and when I try to delete the comment I get the else statement saying not set.

Comment: Could it be because it's actually null because of the typo you have here `$comment_idd`?

Comment: @Dharman no I have two queries and I store each variable as `$comment_id` and `$comment_idd`. I tried both and none work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending a GET form from the browser, the query string will be composed of the inputs from the form. The compiled query string will replace whatever query string is present in `action` attribute.

So, when you submit the form, the query string looks like this

```
?delete_com=
```

There is no `comment_id`.

To solve this problem, either send POST request or make the `comment_id` as a hidden input field.

```
echo "<form action='includes/form_handlers/delete_comment.php' method='GET' >
 <input type='hidden' name='comment_id' value='".htmlspecialchars($comment_idd, ENT_QUOTES)."' />
 <button name='delete_com' class='delete_comment btn-danger'
 >X ".htmlspecialchars($comment_id, ENT_QUOTES)."</button>
</form>
```